# Force Jenkins pipeline to use specific node version

Tags: jenkins, nvm

I have a Jenkinsfile that is supposed to be using nvm to install a specific of nodejs in the pipeline. This pipeline uses a Jenkins Agent which has nvm installed. This is what the Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
    #!groovy

pipeline {
   agent { label 'nvm' }
   options {
    // Add timestamps to the console output
    timestamps()
    // Avoid clutter - only keep the last 15 builds
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '15', artifactNumToKeepStr: '15'))
    }
    environment {
    shortCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim().take(8)
    }
    stages {
       stage('Initialize Build') {
          steps {
          initBuild(commit: env.shortCommit)
          }
       }
      stage('Unit Test') {
    steps {
        echo "Running Tests!"
        sh """#!/bin/bash
            set -exuo pipefail
            /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh use 10.16.3
            /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh alias default 10.16.3
            which node
            node -v
            which nvm.sh
            nvm.sh --version
        """
        }
     }
   }

}
```

When I run the build, I always see this in the stdout:

```
16:00:48  + /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh use 10.16.3
16:00:49  + /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh alias default 10.16.3
16:00:49  + which node
16:00:49  /usr/bin/node
16:00:49  + node -v
16:00:49  v10.14.2
16:00:49  + which nvm.sh
16:00:49  /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh
16:00:49  + nvm.sh --version
```

Im noticing that when I run `which node` it always points to `/usr/bin/node`. Is there a way to overwrite this in the Jenkinsfile so that it actually uses the node version that I configure in nvm? So basically I'm looking to make sure the Jenkins pipeline points the specified node version that nvm set.

Comment: Since nvm installation by default is on a per user basis, you might want to check if the Node.js version you are trying to set as default is installed and available to the Jenkins user by running `nvm list`.

Comment: @DibakarAditya I ran that command but comes back with no output.. So i tried changing a few things like running the nvm install/use as the Jenkins user but it still points back to /usr/bin/node and nvm list doesn't see 10.16.3 as a version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have provided only 'agent' in jenkinsfile. You need to provide additional 'node' as well inside the 'agent'

Make sure node is created on your Jenkins server.

```
   pipeline {
       agent { 
               node {  label 'nvm'} 
             }
    options {
    // Add timestamps to the console output
```

Comment: Didnt work..... still points to /usr/bin/node and not the node version that nvm sets.

Comment: Is your node named as 'nvm'?

Comment: The pipeline works but its pointed to the wrong version of node.

Comment: The question is apparently about the Node.js version being used and not about the Jenkins node. Also, using a `node` block inside an `agent` directive in situations as in this answer is superfluous unless you want to use a custom workspace. See https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/.

Answer (score 0):

set the node path for different version using withENV in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node 10 path directly:

```
/usr/bin/node10 -v
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a `cicd/cicd.properties` file in our React/RN for Web projects. You can specify the node version like this:

```
rnc.yarn.default=. $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm use 14.19.1 && yarn install
```